# Firebase Firestore won't save my user data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save users in my fire store users collection,
when passing in data, it consoles exactly what I want, but when I check fire store, the data is null.

Im using createUserWithEmailAndPassword then passing in data to createUser to create the doc.

```
export function createUser(uid, data) {
  return firestore
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .set({ uid, ...data });
}
```

console logging my data returns

```
{
 uid: ###,
 email: ###,
 name: ###,
 provider: password
}
```

In my fire store collection, it displays,

```
uid: ###,
name: null,
photoUrl: null,   // im not passing photoUrl in the data object
provider: password,
email: ###
```

Comment: what is value for `data` in the first code

Comment: I'm confused.  Your post says that "data is null" but that there are field in Firestore.  Those fields don't get there on their own.  Are you by chance using a third party library for Firestore, something like Redux-Firestore?  Maybe in `createUser()` create a variable: `let myDoc = { uid, ...data};` then `console.log("myData is: ", JSON.stringify(myData,null,2));`, then use myDoc in the call to `.set(myDoc)` ?

Comment: @wzrd which field is not being added as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended as you are unpacking the data object with `...` this will include the standard fields from the firebase Auth profile which includes a name and photoURL. you can see this in your code since you are addign the UID only with the additional data object
`.set({ uid, ...data });`